# Python Regex Overlapping issue Stuck

Tags: python, regex

I have been stuck with this regex

```
# Find the following keywords: sea, sear, search, 
# Find all overlapping keywords 
p = re.compile(r'(sea)+(r?((ch)?))')

pos = 0
while pos<len(s):
    m = p.search(s,pos)
    if m:
       pos = m.end()
       w = m.group()
       g = m.groups()
       #print w,g
       for k in range(len(g)):
         if g[k]:
             w += ', '+g[k]
             print w
         else:
           break

s ='search for searing remarks that mark whether the ark came by sea'
```

I need to find all overlapping keywords too.
However my attempt yields

```
search, sea
search, sea, rch
search, sea, rch, ch
sear, sea
sear, sea, r
sea, sea
```

How should I approach it. I just learned it today. Thanks in Advance

Expected result:
    sea, sear, search for first 'search'
    searing should yield sear, and sea

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: I believe it should be sea, sear, search for first word 'search'. similarly searing should give sea and sear and lastly sea should yield just sea

Comment: Please edit your post to include the expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current regex should be able to detect `sea`, `sear` or `search`. However, there is a slight problem:

```
(sea)+(r?((ch)?))
     ^  ^     ^
     2  1     1
```

At the 2 points that I marked `1`, you are allowing `seach` to be matched with your regex. Since `r` and `ch` are both optional, it allows the possibility of `seach`.

You are allowing `sea` to be repeated, which means `seaseasear` can be matched. Well, it is not that much of a disaster, and you can still determine how many repetition, but it is inconvenient.

Fixed a bit:

```
sea(r(ch)?)?
```

With the regex above, since `?` is greedy, it will try to match before backtracking the case where it matches empty string. Therefore, the search order is `search` --> `sear` --> `sea`.

Since the `re.search` method does not allow multiple matches to start at the same index, it is necessary to process them in a single match. I can't think of any way to give the result directly. Probably checking and inferring is the only way here.

There are many ways to check what is matched here. Check for length of the string in group 0 is one way. Another way is check what is matched in group 2 and group 1.

Comment: regex - sea(r(?:ch)?)? gives me : search, rch
sear, r. I am expecting following results. Search,sear,sea (for first word 'search' in the string. 'searing' in the string should give me sear and sea.

Comment: @user1772218: There is no way to give the result you want. You need to do some inference.

Comment: Thank you so much for looking into it. I really appreciate it. I think you put me on the right path.

Answer (score 1):

You probably are looking for a look-behind assertion. See [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

You should also convert your "r" and "ch" groups into non-capture groups within the first capture group, like this (assuming the word boundaries are always spaces, you can easily generalize this):

```
p = re.compile("(sea(?:r(?:ch)?)?) ")
```

If your keywords are always a chain of prefixes, then you are wasting time by doing the iteration for each position in the string. You simply want to match the prefixes form largest to smallest (ie so the largest ones will match first):

```
p = re.compile("(search|sear|sea)")
```

You can then use a function to split the larger prefixes.

Comment: I tried using look-behind assertion, I get "sre_constants.error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern". I edited the regex to r'((?<=(sea)+r)+ch). Anything wrong?

Comment: Sorry for confusion. Word "search" in the string should give me ---- search, sear, sea. Similarly word "Searing" in the string should give me --- sear, sea. Word "sea" should give me just sea